# shell script interpreter not identifying the path

Tags: shell, sh

I can successfully run the following command in the shell.

```
export ANT_HOME=/users/user1/workspace/apache-ant-1.7.0
```

But when I am adding the same line in a shell script, I am getting the following error.

`/users/user1/workspace/apache-ant-1.7.0': not a valid identifier

The shell interpreter is taking -1.7.0 in the path as a arithmetic operation.

How can I fix this ?

EDIT : the shell script which I am trying to run is here.

```
#!/bin/sh

settingsForANT()
{

export ANT_HOME=/users/user1/workspace/apache-ant-1.7.0
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANT_HOME}/bin

echo $ANT_HOME
echo $PATH

}

settingsForANT
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Can you show a portion of your script where you are setting this variable? Also do you have `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you either have a `$` before the `ANT_HOME` or a space after the `=`, probably the latter.

It's complaining about your path being an invalid *identifier,* meaning it's on the left hand of an assignment, not the right.

If that turns out to be not the case, check the shell you're running the script as. Some do not allow combined `set/export` and you may need:

```
ANT_HOME=whatever; export ANT_HOME
```

Comment: That use of `set` in any `sh`-like shell would set the first positional parameter (`$1`) to the string `ANT_HOME=whatever`.

Comment: +1, though, for space after =, which would make the path a separate argument to `export`, and thus treated as an identifier to mark for export.

Comment: +1. It is working now. The culprit is the trailing space after ANT_HOME.